# issues with template after a ajax request in django

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

i have added like feature to my project 
ajax and django is perfectly working fine ajax is able to send a request and django is able to recieve it and vice versa but the thing where i'm stuck is i cant update it in my template properly ,i'm able to update the changes but that not happening for all objects
whenever i click on like button the count is getting incremented for only one object lets say 
i have two objects with title facebook and instagram 
when i click on facebook the count increments to 1 and click the same button it decrements to 0  its perfectly working but when i click the like button for my instagram object instead of updating its own object its is updating the facebook object the facebook likes counts is incrementing/decrementing 
i'm not sure if the issue is with the template or it is with the ajax part

AJAX:

```
$('button').on('click',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var element=$(this);
$.ajax({

  url: $(this).attr("data-href"),
  type:'GET',
  success:function(response){
    // $('#lik').html(response);
    // console.log(response);
    // alert(response.message);
    // alert('Company likes count is now ' + response.likes_count);
    // document.getElementById('like-count').innerHTML = response.like_count;
    // $('#like_count').html(response.likes_count);
    $('#lik').html(response.likes_count);


    // element.html(' ' + response)
  }
});
});
```

template :

```
 <div class="reaction"  >
              <button type="button" data-href="{% url 'posts:like_post' p.id %}"> <a class="btn text-green" id='lik'><i class="icon ion-thumbsup"></i> </a></button>
                <a class="btn text-red"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i> 0</a>
              </div>
```

views.py

```
def like_post(request,id):
    # id=request.POST.get('psts_id')
    # id=float(id)
    psts = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    is_liked = False
    if psts.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        psts.likes.remove(request.user)
        is_liked = False
        message = 'You disliked this'
    else:
        psts.likes.add(request.user)
        is_liked = True
        message = 'You liked this'

    # total=psts.likes.count.all()
    x=psts.likes.count()
    # x=[x.count() for x in psts.likes.all()]
    ctx = {'likes_count':x, 'message': message}

    # ctx = {'likes_count':[x.as_dict() for x in psts.likes.all()], 'message': message}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(ctx), content_type='application/json')
```

i want to make sure that whenever any user likes any function the template should get updated

according to its object

Comment: `$('#lik').html(response.likes_count)` uses an id selector, so it will hit only the same element with this id (id has to be unique)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know  but i want to know is there any way to change my code structure so that my template will update  every object accordingly

Comment: you declared the variable `element`, why not use this reference to replace html ?

Comment: yeah working now